# Prove that the perpendicular focal chord of a rectangular hyperbola are equal.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

> The original question asked to
>
> Prove that the perpendicular focal chord of a rectangular hyperbola are equal.

For finding the length of the focal chords of a hyperbola, how to use polar /parametric form ??

For it,  what I did was use a parametric form so I found the equation of a point as $(ae + r\cos\theta,r \sin \theta)$, then I would put the point in the  corresponding equation of the hyperbola $ \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ , so I will get a quadratic in $r$.

Let its root be $r_1, r_2$. Since they are on different sides, one will be positive, the other negative. Let $r_1> 0, r_2<0$

I am already provided with $\theta$ in the question.

**Now my question is, for the length, would I need to take the sum of the roots or their difference??**